# Restore deleted file using the gerrit UI

Tags: git, gerrit

I deleted files from an older gerrit change :

[image]

I wanted to know how to restore it.
That's strange because it seems to be a quite simple question but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: Have you already merged this change? Or is it open?

Comment: It is opened but I commited another change on the same project afterwards. So I can't amend this commit. @MarceloÁviladeOliveira

Comment: Actually you can. Depending of your project submit type and the existing conflict you will just need to rebase your change and push a new patchset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1) Abandon your change clicking in the "Abandon" button at the change screen. The change won't be merged.

2) Amend the commit and push a new patchset restoring the specific files.